# condition template in ansible

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I have this template (`set_ip.j2`):

```
{% if '{{ansible_env.SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2]}}' == '{{ ip_ssh }}' %}
   address = {{ ip_db }}
   name='db1'
{% endif %}
```

but this condition not work! I want `address` and `name` set by this value in the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever use nested expressions in Jinja2:

```
{% if ansible_env.SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2] == ip_ssh %}
   address = {{ ip_db }}
   name='db1'
{% endif %}
```

Comment: there's lack of context and data to answer why your config is empy

Comment: thnaks agian @Konstantin Suvorov. i mistake syntax ;) .